# Convert a negative number to 2's complement in Java

Tags: java, math

Is the following way a correct way to compute 2's complement of a number?

```
if(n<0)
   n = ~n+1;
```

Comment: Or `n = -n;`. Or `n = Math.abs(n)`. Beware of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` though.

Answer (score 0):

The 2's complement of any integer `n` is `~n + 1`.

Since this applies to *all* integers, regardless of sign, you don't need the condition.